# Pandas series of datetimes in python

Tags: python, datetime, pandas

I have a series that is purely datetimes.  Call it `series1`.

How can I extract the months from the series in the most efficient way possible to have a new series of just the months?

For example.

```
series1.month
```

does not work.  But for every row, it would work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Pandas version 0.14 and older, you can use `apply` to extract the dates from the `datetime` values:

```
series1.apply(lambda x: x.month)
```

In 0.15, a new `datetime` Series accessor makes the operation much simpler (thanks @chrisb):

```
series1.dt.month
```

Here is a [link to the documentation](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.15.0/whatsnew.html#whatsnew-0150-dt).

Comment: In 0.15 you can use the new `dt` accessor, like `series1.dt.month`

Comment: Thanks @chrisb - I haven't looked at 0.15 yet! I'll add a link to the documentation into the answer.